# The Advanced Custom Fields plugin works on Localhost but Hosting does not work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I made my theme in Localhost and I used the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, all ok.

When I send the theme to the server, I install the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, the "Create Fields" button does not work and I can not create the fields I made in localhost.

Look -

**1. In the Localhost:**

[image]

**2. In my Hosting:**

[image]

**When I click on "Criar Campos" ("Create Fields") nothing happens.**

I tried to export but at the time of import says there is no file, but there is.

I do not know what could be wrong, since everything in localhost is in the hosting.

My Console show this:

[image]

```
 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
acf-input.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
select2.full.min.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
acf-field-group.min.js?ver=5.7.12:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
    at acf-field-group.min.js?ver=5.7.12:1
    at acf-field-group.min.js?ver=5.7.12:1
post.php?post=72&action=edit:1150 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
    at post.php?post=72&action=edit:1150
post.php?post=72&action=edit:1154 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
    at post.php?post=72&action=edit:1154
2/wp-admin/post.php?post=72&action=edit#:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've update the wordpress core and acf plugin. Please enable the debug mode on wp-config.php, find this line define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); and set to true, then tell us what it says when you create a field.

Comment: Hi @RomelIndemne I made define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); but don´t show anything, I put my console errors of the Chrome.

Comment: @RomelIndemne It´s show me Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (1) in /home/u552207004/domains/residuodevalor.com/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4212